# javascript if statement if url contains substring

Tags: javascript, html, url

So basically I want to do something different for a site if the url contains a specific string, lets say: `'foo'`

So this is what I have:

```
var url = document.URL;
var substring = 'foo';
if(the substring is in the url){
//do something
}
else{
//do something
};
```

So what would go in the `if()` to make this possible?

Comment: Search: javascript string contains substring

Comment: (sadly Stack Overflow won't let me point you to lmgtfy…)

Comment: [Let me help you](http://bit.ly/10JUfYN)

Comment: @Dave, short links work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method

```
// Function is used to determine whether a string contains another string
function contains(search, find) {
    ///<summary>Sees if a string contains another string</summary>
    ///<param type="string" name="search">The string to search in</param>
    ///<param type="string" name="find">The string to find</param>
    ///<returns type="bool">A boolean value indicating whether the search string contained the find string</returns>
    return search.indexOf(find) !== -1;
}
```

Here's some sample usage:

```
var url = document.URL;
var substring = 'foo';
if (contains(url.toLowerCase(), substring.toLowerCase()) { 
// Contains string
}
```

The contains function is **case sentitive**, however; as demonstrated in my example, you can make it incasesensitive by calling the [StringPrototype.toLowerCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.stringprototype.tolowercase%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Method

Answer (score 1):

You may use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for example :

```
if (url.indexOf(substring)>=0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a forward-looking answer, and won't work in current implementations.

ECMAScript 6 is currently defining a `String.prototype.contains` method. This will allow you to do:

```
if (url.contains(substring)) {
```

Again, this is a future addition. Currently ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) is being drafted, and this could technically be removed, though it doesn't seem likely.

Current draft:

> ***15.5.4.24 String.prototype.contains (searchString, position = 0 )***
>
> The contains method takes two arguments, searchString and position, and performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let `O` be `CheckObjectCoercible(this value)`.
> 2. Let `S` be `ToString(O)`.
> 3. `ReturnIfAbrupt(S)`.
> 4. Let `searchStr` be `ToString(searchString)`.
> 5. `ReturnIfAbrupt(searchStr)`.
> 6. Let `pos` be `ToInteger(position)`. (If `position` is `undefined`, this step produces the value `0`).
> 7. `ReturnIfAbrupt(pos)`.
> 8. Let `len` be the number of elements in `S`.
> 9. Let `start` be `min(max(pos, 0), len)`.
> 10. Let `searchLen` be the number of characters in `searchStr`.
> 11. If there exists any integer `k` not smaller than start such that `k + searchLen` is not greater than `len`, and for all nonnegative integers `j` less than `searchLen`, the character at position `k+j` of `S` is the same as the character at position `j` of `searchStr`, return `true`; but if there is no such integer `k`, return `false`.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding this answer, please ask instead of down-voting, though I don't know how it could possibly be more clear or well documented than what I've described.